# Magento2 Display out of stock products at last

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock

We have to display out of stock products at last in the list pages.

Let me if anybody have an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
  $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
         ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'], 
         "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", ['is_in_stock']
  );
  $collection->getSelect()->order(['is_in_stock desc']);
```

Comment: sure, let me know if any issue

Comment: Ok sure I will inform

Comment: Hi Nikunj which file exactly we need to edit

Comment: Where i have to add the above code

Comment: Hi @ Nikunj iam editing layer.php file,

Comment: i have added the code getProductcollection() , iam getting the following  error: {"0":"Notice: Undefined variable: subject in \vendor\\magento\\module-catalog\\Model\\Layer.php on line 150","1":"#0

Comment: change $subject to $collection and try

Comment: find the code below and confirm it is correct or not

Comment: if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];

            $collection = $collection->getCollection();
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'], 
                     "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", ['is_in_stock']
                    );
             $collection->getSelect()->order(['is_in_stock ASC']);
        }

Comment: change it to 'is_in_stock desc' cache flush and check again. and let me know result

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::getCollection() i

Comment: iam getting the above error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78525/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-shivashankar-m).

Comment: Hello thanks for the solution Nikunj but I am also getting "cannot define a correlation name '_inventory_table' more than once" error, as @shivashankarm is getting - So, Is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

just happened upon this thread... If anyone's still having issues and getting the `_inventory_table correlation error` using the aforementioned solution, try this in the `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php` file.

For me, there's already a join with the `cataloginventory_stock_status` table.
Tested in 2.1.7 only.

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];

        $collection->getSelect()->order(['stock_status DESC']); //ADD THIS

    } else {
        $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Let me know if this works out for ya!

Answer (score 0):

**How to display out of stock products at the end of the list page in Magento 2 :-**

You can create a custom module or add this code in the existing module for display out of stock product at the end of the page.

Here, I am creating a custom module. so first Create `registration.php` and `module.xml` file for creating a module. I hope you have created both files for define module,

For Collection of product generate from `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection` file. We need to create a plugin for the `load()` function. we need to set our custom condition for out of stock product to `beforeLoad()` function.

Create a `di.xml` file,

Path, `app/code/Vishal/OutOfStock/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--  out of stock product at end of list -->
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <plugin name="Vishal_OutOfStock::OutofstockEnd" type="Vishal\OutOfStock\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create `Toolbar.php` file, File Path, `app/code/Vishal/OutOfStock/Plugin/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Vishal Thakur
 * @package Vishal_OutOfStock
 */

namespace Vishal\OutOfStock\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject
     * @param bool $printQuery
     * @param bool $logQuery
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeLoad(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $subject, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        $orderBy = $subject->getSelect()->getPart(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $outOfStockOrderBy = array('is_salable DESC');
        /* reset default product collection filter */
        $subject->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $subject->getSelect()->order($outOfStockOrderBy);

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
}
```

Clear Cache and Check-in front. All the Out of stock products will display at end of listing page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free extension to show out of stock items at the end of the catalog.

https://github.com/bikashkaushik/magento2-OutOfStockLast